# How to invoke Jython interpreter from python source code in Windows

Tags: python, jython

Stated [here](http://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#making-jython-scripts-executable), one can invoke Jython in source code in Unix platforms.

I've installed Jython and put the directory in PATH in windows.

How could I set this up to invoke Jython from .py code automatically? Thanks.

---

Make the example more specific and clear:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jython
import sys
sys.path.append("./package.jar")
import org.abc.name
```

`ImportError: No module named org.abc.name`

And if I run `Jython bar.py` from cmd, it did work. But running `Python bar.py` fails with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ImportError` is already a Python error, so it looks like jython is working. You need, however, to set up the path.

If `xxx` stands for one of your *Python* modules, set up [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) to contain the appropriate directory before importing it.

If `xxx` stands for one of your *Java* modules, set up the [Java Classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) to contain the appropriate directory or jar.

If `xxx` stands for a built-in module, it is probably not supported by jython yet. Have a look at the [list of modules supported by jython](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/indexprogress.html). Some newer modules that are available on other Python platforms (such as `json`) are not yet available in jython.

Comment: I did set sys.path. I updated the question, could you have another look?

Comment: @Flake `sys.path` is for Python modules. To load Java code, set up the classpath. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar path is relative. Under Jython, the base path for the script is calculated in a different way than under CPython.

I bet that it would have worked from the beginning if you just added the full path to the jar to sys.path rather than the relative one.